# Publish progress using aquery

Tags: android-query, aquery

I need to show the file downloading progress using AQuery, is there any way showing the % of the file download instead of just showing a plain progress dialog  (aq.progress(new ProrgressDialog(mContext)...))

Comment: did you found your solution ?

Answer (score 0):

make progress dialog like this and set on AQuery-

```
private ProgressDialog dialog;
private AQuery aq;
```

in your onCreate

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setTitle("AQuery");
    dialog.setMessage("Downloading....Please wait !");
    dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    dialog.setMax(100);
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);

    aq = new AQuery(this);
    aq.id(R.id.imgAQuery).progress(dialog).image("your url",false,false);
```